# How to use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 in a custom Adapter?

Tags: android, listview

I have to use a custom adapter for my ListView in Android, because I want to create a special look of the ListViews items.

My Adapter currently looks that way:

```
public class RecordingListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<Recording> recordings;
    Context context;

   public RecordingListAdapter(Context context, List<Recording> recordings) {
       this.context = context;
       this.recordings = recordings;
   }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return recordings.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return recordings.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recorder_list_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.recordingTitle);
        TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        TextView duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        TextView tags = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tags);

        Recording recording = recordings.get(position);

        title.setText(recording.getTitle());
        date.setText(context.getString(R.string.date) + ": " + new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(recording.getDate().getTime()).toString());
        duration.setText(context.getString(R.string.duration) + ": " + recording.getDuration().toString());
        tags.setText(context.getString(R.string.tags) + ": " + recording.getTagsAsString());

        return convertView;

    }
}
```

In my layout I am already using a navigation drawer, that uses an ArrayAdapter with the following properties:

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                mMenuEntries
        ));
```

I want my List to look like the drawer list, especially with the selected items.

So how can I use this android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 in my custom adapter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the answer by myself:

Having a look on simple_list_item_activated_1.xml I saw:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

The attribute

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

is the interesting one. I set this one as an attribute into my RelativeLayout of my custom list item and got finally the same style.

In addition: To set the first item checked in your list, add something like

```
mListView.setItemChecked(0, true);
```

to your ListFragment inside onViewCreated.

Answer (score 0):

Just inflate correct layout item in Your Adapter class inside method getView().

```
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, parent, false);
    }
```

Comment: That way my custom layout, stored in R.layout.recorder_list_item, gets lost, or?